# Help with SharePoint Calculated Field Multiple Values

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, calculated-column-formula

I have the following formula on a calculated field that searches the value funnel status for values, then sets as live or active. Rather than search does the field contain a specific value, I would like to be have a check if the field equals. How would the formula change?

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("EarlyEngagement",[funnel status])),"active",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("DRFP (Active) ",[funnel status])),"active",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("DRFP (Non-Active) ",[funnel status])),"active",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Post Proposal Submission ",[funnel status])),"active",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("DRFP Questions ",[funnel status])),"live",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("RFI",[funnel status])),"live",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("RFP",[funnel status])),"live",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("BAFO",[funnel status])),"live",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Orals",[funnel status])),"live",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Quals",[funnel status])),"live",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ENs",[funnel status])),"live",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("FRP",[funnel status])),"live",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Bridge",[funnel status])),"live",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Contract MOD",[funnel status])),"live",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Unsolicited",[funnel status])),"live","")))))))))))))))
```

So basically if:

> funnel status = EarlyEngagement (Active), EarlyEngagement (Non-Active), DRFP (Active), DRFP (Non-Active) or Post Proposal Submission then field would equal active
>
> funnel status = DFRP Questions, RFI, RFP, BAFO, Orals Prep, Orals, Quals, ENs, FRP, Bridge, Contract MOD or Unsolicited would equal live

I tried this but it's not working

```
=IF(("Early Engagement",[funnel status]),"active",IF("DRFP(Active)",[funnel status]),"active",IF("DRFP(Non-Active)",[funnel status]),"active",IF("PostProposal Submission",[funnel status]),"active",IF("DRFPQuestions",[funnel status]),"live",IF("RFI",[funnel status]),"live",IF("RFP",[funnel status]),"live",IF("BAFO",[funnel status]),"live",IF("Orals",[funnel status]),"live",IF("Quals",[funnel status]),"live",IF("ENs",[funnel status]),"live",IF("FRP",[funnel status]),"live",IF("Bridge",[funnel status]),"live",IF("Contract MOD",[funnel status]),"live",IF("Unsolicited",[funnel status]),"live","")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an OR to do your multiple tests OR(cond 1, cond 2, cond3....)

```
OR([funnel status] = "EarlyEngagement (Active)", [funnel status] = "EarlyEngagement (Non-Active)", .....
```

so

```
IF(OR(x1,x2,x3), "active", IF(OR(y,y,y), "live" , ""))
```

Comment: so would the calculated field look like this:

Comment: tried this and got syntax error

=IF(OR([funnel status] = “Early Engagement (Active)”, [funnel status] = “Early Engagement (Non-Active)”, [funnel status] = “DRFP (Active)”, [funnel status] = “DRFP (Non-Active)”, [funnel status] = “Post Proposal Submission”), "active", IF(OR([funnel status] = “DRFP Question”, [funnel status] = “RFI”, [funnel status] = “RFP”), "live" , ""))

Comment: looks OK to me, everything seems to match up. When I copy/pasted it, I got smart quotes instead of straight quotes, so double check your quotes.