# Calculated Formula how to make it more succinct

Tags: calculated-column-formula

I want to do the following:

If Risk Level = 0 "Accepted", if Risk Level = 2, 3 or 4 "Watch", if Risk Level = 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 or 11 "Plan", if Risk Level >= 12 "Treat"

I have got this so far:

```
=IF([Risk Level]>=12,"TREAT",IF([Risk Level]=1,"ACCEPTED", IF([Risk Level]=2,"WATCH",IF([Risk Level]=3,"WATCH",IF([Risk Level]=4,”WATCH”,IF([Risk Level]=0,”ACCEPTED”,"PLAN"))))))
```

but is there a way to make the 2,3,4 bit more succinct?

Thanks! 
Also is there a way to colour the text based on that result?

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218625/help-with-sharepoint-calculated-field-multiple-values?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0):

For that you can use the OR formula.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx

```
=OR([Column1]>[Column2], [Column1]<[Column3])
```

In your case in would be something like this :

```
=IF([Risk Level]>=12,"TREAT",IF([Risk Level]=1,"ACCEPTED", IF(OR([Risk Level]=2,[Risk Level]=3,[Risk Level]=4),"WATCH",IF([Risk Level]=0,"ACCEPTED","PLAN"))))))
```

EDIT: 
As for the colors, you would have to output HTML instead of plain text. Depending of your environment, there is extra work to achieve it. Have a look at this article for starter.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4032106/handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-fields

Comment: Thank you so much for replying to this, is there a way that based on the result it then colours the text?

Comment: @Kim, "colors": Which version of SharePoint? 2007, 2010, 2013, 2016, Online? The solution depends on which version, and your administrator's decision of supporting HTML in calculated columns. See: http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2018/01/adding-html-to-sharepoint-columns-color.html